# Adapting code from one-sided p-values to two sided

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I have some code from Rapach, Strauss and Zhou (2013), Journal of finance.

It computes bootstrapping p-values for one-sided hypothesis tests,

```
H0: B=0 against H1: B>0
```

Is it possible for me to adapt this code to compute the hypothesis test:

```
H0: B=0 against H1: B\=0
```

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Computing statistics for wild bootstrapped pseudo samples
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

stats_boot=zeros(N+1,N,B);
for b=1:B;
    for j=1:N;
        [results_j_star,R_squared_j_star]=...
            Estimate_Granger_pairwise_GMM(Y_star(:,:,b),...
            Y_star(:,:,b),X_1_star(:,:,b),X_2_star(:,:,b),j);
        for i=1:(N-1);
            if j==1;
                stats_boot(i+1,j,b)=results_j_star(i,2);
            else
                if i<j;
                    stats_boot(i,j,b)=results_j_star(i,2);
                else
                    stats_boot(i+1,j,b)=results_j_star(i,2);
                end;
            end;
        end;
        stats_boot(N+1,j,b)=results_j_star(end,2);
        disp([b j]);
    end;
end;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Computing wild bootstrapped p-values
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

for j=1:N;
    for i=1:N+1;
        stats_boot_i_j=stats_boot(i,j,:);
        stats_p_i_j=stats_boot_i_j>results_all(2,j,i);
        results_all(3,j,i)=sum(stats_p_i_j)/B;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original code, the line `stats_p_i_j=stats_boot_i_j>results_all(2,j,i);` identifies all the values where the results from the bootstrapping are greater than the actual results. This is a conventional way to do a 'one-sided' test. You need to do a two-sided test which corresponds to `H0: B=0 against H1: B\=0`. To convert to a two-sided test, we just need to count all the bootstrapped values which are either greater or less than (basically not equal to) the actual results.

Therefore, in the code, instead of using `>`, you use `~=`. The modified code would look like this:

```
for j=1:N;
    for i=1:N+1;
        stats_boot_i_j=stats_boot(i,j,:);
        %changes begin here
        stats_p_i_j=stats_boot_i_j~=results_all(2,j,i);
        %changes end here
        results_all(3,j,i)=sum(stats_p_i_j)/B;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: @TonyChivers I have edited the answer to include my reasoning for the change. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: do you think your answer is wrong following the other answer provided?

Comment: I beg to differ. The other answer talks about how to determine the significance of an obtained p-value whereas the OP specifically asked for how to calculate the required p-value. The calculation is independent of the test for significance. In ttest also, the t-value calculations are independent whereas the significance is calculated using the method provided in the second answer

Answer (score 2):

I believe the original answer is incorrect.

If we think of the hypothesis test for a two-tailed is:

```
H0: b=0, HA:b\=0
```

Then the above answer only tells us when the t does not equal the critical value, which will be basically all the time.

But think about a t-test,

A two-tailed should be,

```
Reject H0 is |t|>t_(alpha/2)
```

So the OP needs to change the code to account for this.

This should be a comment not an answer but I have rep less than 50!

Comment: Your answer talks about how to determine the significance of an obtained p-value whereas the OP specifically asked for how to calculate the required p-value. The calculation is independent of the test for significance. In ttest also, the t-value calculations are independent whereas the significance is calculated using the method provided in your answer.

Comment: Also, the argument for including `alpha` applies for one-sided tests as well. Since, the original code had no provision for it, I would suspect it is not required in this case.

Comment: Agreed, but can we all agree that the other answer is wrong and should be removed. See my answer as a long comment.